# Advice on how to structure audio recorded from travel for products / free podcasts

Tags: post-production

Whilst cycling from the UK to India, around Nepal, and Mongolia & living in the Republic of Georgia I recorded sound: some music, narrative, interviews, background noise etc. 
I am in the process of working through the audio and compiling it into consumable products / podcasts for the public. This is happening post-humously as unfortunately I didn't have a great plan for the audio before the trip. My question is what kind of products can I create from what I have recorded? I am planning to break them down into stories, interviews, and narrative, and the end products will likely be some photos slideshows with narrative background sounds, a compilation of Georgian singing, a series of interviews about climate change and a series of interviews about other social organisations where I conducted interviews. I know this isn't a specific question, but any advice would be appreciated. If anyone is interested in giving advice then it would be great to have a conversation via Skype or email.

Comment: This is really entirely too broad for a Q/A type question.  This is effectively asking how to edit, which is an entire field.  A documentary is the most obvious answer, but how to edit that together really depends on the amounts, types and qualities of the media that you have.  It is both too broad and too localized to be a good fit for this site.  If you have more specific, general purpose issues you encounter with how to make some particular kind of media work well together, it might be generally useful and specific enough to answer, but as it currently stands, it really isn't.

Comment: You might try the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/733/audio-video-chat) to see if anyone has ideas since that supports more broad and interactive discussion.

Comment: I understand the format, but this is one of those 'just starting out' questions. Sorry about that.

Comment: no problem, as someone just starting out, it would be hard for you to know how broad the question really is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the pictures (or any apt images) with the audio and make a small representative video of the whole (or sections of the) trip - put it on youtube to advertise there are more detailed videos that are for sale and, most importantly have patience waiting for the dollars to come in.

If you really have some stuff that is marketable then you've got to find a way of protecting your product from being copied and distributed.